# Magento How can I save a new attribute in the order item table

Tags: magento

I've created a new attribute 'Envases' on the sales_flat_order_item. I've created the display control in the cart page, but I don't know how to save it on the data base.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

try {
    $installer->run("
    ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_order_item')} ADD `envases` VARCHAR( 225 ) NOT NULL;
    ");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
}

$installer->installEntities();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DushyantJoshi !!, I had to change the query for this one: 'ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item ADD envases INT(11) NOT NULL' and it worked perfectly. You've saved me a lot of work. But now I need to know where add my php code to save the value of the input in my new field.

Comment: Glad to know that your problem solved. Of course you needed to modify.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you to execute script on any file.

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

    $setup->addAttribute('sales_order', 'Envases', array(
        'group'             => 'General',
        'label'             => 'Label frontend',
        'note'              => '',
        'type'              => 'string',    //backend_type
        'input'             => 'text', //frontend_input
        'frontend_class'    => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
        'required'          => true,
        'visible_on_front'  => true,
        'apply_to'          => 'simple',
        'is_configurable'   => false,
        'used_in_product_listing'   => false,
        'sort_order'        => 5,
    ));
```

After running script remove these codes.

Now your attribute will save automatically.

Comment: I've tried that but I don't know where is created the new attribute. this script creates a new field in some table on the database? I need to create it in sales_flat_order_item table.

Comment: Use order_item instead of sales_order.

Comment: @Lorena - Why you need to create such fields in `sales_flat_order_item` ?

Answer (score 0):

For any custom attribute which you need to add into order_item table , you need to follow the following steps,

1.In your custom module,add an upgrade script,

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_quote_item
  ADD COLUMN `envases` int(11) NULL default ''

");

$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item
  ADD COLUMN `envases` int(11) NULL default ''

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Where 'envases' is your custom attribute,

as when a product is added into cart in Magento, it initates a quote object which stores your cart data.

2.So once you have saved your value into quote,

```
      $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
      $quote->setEnvases('someValue');
      $quote->save();
```

In your config.xml, add this code

```
 <global>

       <fieldsets>
                      <sales_convert_quote>
                          <envases>
                              <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                          </envases>
       </fieldsets>
    </global>
```

Here * indicating that the field name in sales_flat_quote_item and sales_flat_order_item tables is the same.

Once you click place order, the merged config.xml nodes will be read and it will update your  order_item table.

Hope this helps!